# Find Last Row from invitation table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to come up with a SQL Server code to solve this problem. I want to find which ID  has an open invitation.Please use the following table as one sample (original table has 1000+ rows but following the same pattern) :

| ID | InvitationCreateDate | InvitationClosedDate | InvitationReopendDate | InvitationStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1/2/2018 |  |  | Opened |
| 0 | 1/2/2018 | 1/2/2019 |  | Closed |
| 1 | 1/2/2019 |  |  | Opened |
| 1 | 1/2/2019 | 1/2/2020 |  | Closed |
| 2 | 1/3/2019 |  |  | Opened |
| 3 | 1/4/2019 |  |  | Opened |
| 3 | 1/4/2019 | 1/7/2020 |  | Closed |
| 3 | 1/4/2019 |  | 1/8/2020 | ReOpened |
| 3 | 1/4/2019 | 1/10/2020 |  | Closed |
| 3 | 1/4/2019 |  | 1/15/2020 | ReOpened |
| 4 | 2/6/2019 |  |  | Opened |
| 4 | 2/6/2019 | 2/7/2019 |  | Closed |
| 4 | 2/6/2019 |  | 2/10/2019 | ReOpened |
| 4 | 2/6/2019 | 2/20/2019 |  | Closed |
| 4 | 2/6/2019 |  | 3/10/2019 | ReOpened |
| 4 | 2/6/2019 | 3/20/2019 |  | Closed |

Comment: Please include your expected results for your sample data and the query you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to get the open invitation only. For example, from the provided data I expect to get this:

Comment: I included the expected results at the end of my original post. Note that DateDiff is calculated using InvitationCreateDate when the Invitation is Opened and using InvitationReopendDate when the invitation is Reopened.

Comment: I tried to use the RANK function to give levels or row numbers to the rows based on the ID. This can be used to create a foreach loop that uses a list with distinct IDs to select the last row of each loop and insert each selected row in a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if your data had a unique key, however the following produces your desired results using `window functions` to identify the most recent relevant invitation:

```
with cte as (
    select *,
    Row_Number() over(partition by id order by Coalesce(InvitationReopendDate, InvitationClosedDate, InvitationCreateDate) desc) rn
    from t
)
select *, DateDiff(day,InvitationCreateDate, GetDate()) [DateDiff]
from cte
where rn=1 and InvitationStatus in ('opened','reopened')
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! You mention about having a unique key. How the code will look like if I add a unique ID to the original table?

Comment: It would remove ambiguity and offer alternative methods using aggregation. for example, if an invitiation ID is closed and reopened on the same date, is it currently closed or open?

Comment: In that case the invitation is open.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DATEFDIFF` to get the difference between two dates

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, CONVERT(date, '1/3/2019'), GETDATE())
```

Your query should look like this

```
SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(d, InvitationCreateDate, GETDATE()) as DaysOpen
FROM Table
WHERE InvitationStatus = 'Opened'
```